# Is there a way to ignore the 'Unreachable statement' error?

Tags: java

Is it possible to somehow ignore this error? I find it much easier to just put `return` in front of the code I don't want to run than to comment it (when the comments overlap and behave badly)...

Comment: why! o why! writing a code which your fellow programmer hate you for?!

Comment: @Nishant: I often use `if (2 > 1) return;` for debugging purposes.

Comment: @Nishant It's just for debugging, I don't leave chunks of code lying around unless I directly work with them.

Answer (score 120, accepted):

No. It's a compile time error. So you **must** get rid of it before running your class.

What I usually do is put a fake `if` statement in front of it. Something like:

```
if(true)
    return;
// unwanted code follows. no errors.
i++;
j++;
```

With this code, you will not get a `Unreachable statement` error. And you will get what you want.

Comment: You can replace `if (1==1)` with `if (true)` since 1==1 is always true.

Comment: coming from c++ it feels a bit odd how java tries to protect you and holds your hand and then sometimes pulls you in the wrong direction. Nice workaround, it also has the advantage that anyhow a `if (true)` signals that there is something fishy going on and the danger of removing it later is a bit reduced

Answer (score 4):

```
33. if (1==1) return;
34. System.out.println("Hello world!");
```

It works in other languages too. But ByteCode without row 34.

Comment: Javac seems to be fine with `if (true)...`.  The compiler will still remove the conditional as a builtin base level optimization, but will not trigger an Unreachable Code error.

Answer (score 3):

It isn't possible to ignore this error since it is an error according to the [Java Language Specification](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/statements.doc.html#236365).

You might also want to look at this post: [Unreachable code error vs. dead code warning in Java under Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2141029/unreachable-code-error-vs-dead-code-warning-in-java-under-eclipse)

Answer (score 0):

If you want disable/enable certain piece of code many times trick from old C may help you:

```
some_code();
more_code();
// */

/*
some_code();
more_code();
// */
```

Now you need only to write `/*` at the beginning

Answer (score -12):

you have to fix that [unreachable code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unreachable_code#Examples).

```
public void display(){
  return; //move the return statement to appropriate place
  int i;
}
```

compiler will not compile your source code.
you have to take care of your source code that every line is reachable to compiler.